# How to run a promise chain in parallel

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I found the following code through the MDN documentation.

```
var resolveAfter2Seconds = function() {
  console.log("starting slow promise");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(20);
      console.log("slow promise is done");
    }, 2000);
  });
};

var resolveAfter1Second = function() {
  console.log("starting fast promise");
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(10);
      console.log("fast promise is done");
    }, 1000);
  });
};

var parallel = function() {
  console.log('==PARALLEL with Promise.then==');
  resolveAfter2Seconds().then((message)=>console.log(message));
  resolveAfter1Second().then((message)=>console.log(message));
}
```

And as a result of the execution I thought then each of the promises would be parallel executions without order guarantee.

But I wrote the code below, which seems to be guaranteed order.

```
const promiseFunction1 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let result = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            result += 1;
        }
        resolve(result);
    })
}

const promiseFunction2 = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let result = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            result += 1;
        }
        resolve(result);
    })
}

const parallel = () => {
    promiseFunction1()
        .then(res => console.log(res));
    promiseFunction2()
        .then(res => console.log(res));
}
```

What's the difference between the two codes?

**Appendix**

Are the two codes below the same?

```
1.
const parallel = () => {
    promiseFunction1()
        .then(res => console.log(res));
    promiseFunction2()
        .then(res => console.log(res));
}

2.
const parallel = () => {
    promiseFunction1()
        .then(res1 => {
            console.log(res1);
            promiseFunction2()
                .then(res2 => {
                    console.log(res2);
                })
        });
}
```

Comment: a chain can't be parallel ... to "run" promises in parallel one usually uses `Promise.all`

Comment: @bravo Doesn't Promise.all return the results sequentially to the array in the order of the array passed as argument?
Is this also guaranteed order?

Comment: Yes, Promise.all returns the results in an Array that is in the same order as the Array of Promises given to it ... they run in parallel ... and the result order (within the Array) is guaranteed, no matter what order the promises resolve in

Comment: @bravo
Is it correct to understand that the execution of Promise.all is parallel but the return of the results is in order?

And if you don't mind, I would appreciate checking the code I added to the Appendix.

Comment: Appendix, no ... the first runs in Parallel, the second is a pyramid of doom that Promises were designed to fix

Comment: `return of the results is in order` no ... the result is an Array whose values are the results of the Promises given to Promise.all in the same order (as in the first Promise result will be result[0], second will be result[1] etc) ... the order in which the Promises resolve is irrelevant, because they run in Parallel ... only when all promises resolve will the Promise.all promise resolve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Promise constructor is completely synchronous (unless you invoke something else asynchronous like `setTimeout` or another Promise). In the second code, the `promiseFunction1` runs and *immediately* calls `resolve` synchronously. Same for `promiseFunction2`. So, the first Promise created (here, the one from `promiseFunction1`) will resolve before the second, no matter the possibly-expensive synchronous operations that each `promiseFunction` runs.

The `promiseFunction1` Promise resolves immediately and first, so it goes onto the microtask queue first, so its associated `.then` runs first.

Expensive synchronous code is generally not a good idea to run on the main thread, because it'll block the UI - if you're ever in this situation, consider moving it to a worker instead, if possible.

For your first code:

> I thought then each of the promises would be parallel executions without order guarantee.

Because the `resolveAfter2Seconds` resolves after 2 seconds, and the `resolveAfter1Second` resolves after 1 second, it's pretty much guaranteed that the 1-second Promise will resolve first.

> Are the two codes below the same?

Not at all. In the first, both `promiseFunction`s run immediately, when `parallel` is called. In the second, the `promiseFunction2` runs only after the `promiseFunction1` resolves.

Answer (score 0):

Saying *`Promise` chain* usually means a series of `then()` calls, explicitly with the intent of running them in order, but in an asynchronous way, waiting for some event between the steps.

Just instead of writing a deepening series of nested callbacks...

```js
function delay2s(callback){
  setTimeout(callback,2000);
}

delay2s(()=>{
  log.innerText="1.";
  delay2s(()=>{
    log.innerText+=" 2.";
    delay2s(()=>{
      log.innerText+=" 3.";
      delay2s(()=>{
        log.innerText+=" 4.";
        delay2s(()=>{
          log.innerText+=" 5.";
          delay2s(()=>{
            log.innerText+=" and Done.";
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<span id="log">Soon</span>
```

... you can stay at one "sane" level:

```js
function delay2s(){
  return new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>resolve(),2000));
}

delay2s().then(()=>{
  log.innerText="1.";
  return delay2s();
}).then(()=>{
  log.innerText+=" 2.";
  return delay2s();
}).then(()=>{
  log.innerText+=" 3.";
  return delay2s();
}).then(()=>{
  log.innerText+=" 4.";
  return delay2s();
}).then(()=>{
  log.innerText+=" 5.";
  return delay2s();
}).then(()=>{
  log.innerText+=" and Done.";
});
```

```html
<span id="log">Soon</span>
```

And having multiple independent `Promise`s does not mean that they are *running* together, but they are *waiting* together.
Of course there are some nice auxiliaries for this case too. Like waiting for a number of events, and do something when all of them have completed could look like some nasty, named callback coupled with some even nastier counter:

```js
let counter=5;
function tryfinal(){
  if(--counter>0)return;
  log.innerText+=" all Done.";
}

for(let i=0;i<counter;i++){
  setTimeout(()=>{
    log.innerText=(log.innerText=="Soon"?"":log.innerText+" ")+(i+1)+".";
    tryfinal();
  },4000*Math.random());
}
```

```html
<span id="log">Soon</span>
```

Or it could use `Promise.all/Settled()`:

```js
let promises=[];
for(let i=0;i<5;i++){
  promises.push(new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>{
    log.innerText=(log.innerText=="Soon"?"":log.innerText+" ")+(i+1)+".";
    resolve();
  },4000*Math.random())));
}

Promise.all(promises).then(()=>log.innerText+=" and Done.");
```

```html
<span id="log">Soon</span>
```

---

If you want to actively do something in parallel, you need threads, which means [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API). This example counts upwards for a couple seconds on two threads, reporting progress from time to time(it cooks with the CPU during that time, you can check with some performance monitoring application of the OS you are on):

```js
let limit=5000000000;
let report=100000000;
if(limit>Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)
  log.innerText="No, you do not want that.";
else {
  let workertext="data:text/plain,"
      +escape("for(let i=0;i<="+limit+";i++)"
      +"  if(i%"+report+"===0)"
      +"    postMessage(i);"
      +"postMessage('Done');");
  console.log(workertext);
  let w1=new Worker(workertext);
  let w2=new Worker(workertext);
  w1.onmessage=m=>log1.innerText+=" "+m.data;
  w2.onmessage=m=>log2.innerText+=" "+m.data;
}
```

```html
<div id="log1">Worker1: </div>
<div id="log2">Worker2: </div>
```

Side remark: it is interesting to see how counting slows down after stepping out of the range of signed 32-bit integers (2100000000 -> 2200000000 in the log, or the actual border is 2147483647 -> 2147483648). At least in my Chrome.